# Is it possible to integrate IdentityServer3 with BOX?

Tags: asp.net-identity, box-api, box, identityserver3

I was researching SSO solution using OpenID Connect. I don't want to use google, facebook or twitter for our LOB applications. Azure AD looked to be promising initially but after playing with it for couple of months we have decided not use it for several reasons.

Basically we have .NET, AngularJS, Node applications, and we also want our users to have access to third party [BOX](https://www.box.com/) service. So once user sign-in he/she should be able to access .NET, AngularJS and BOX without re-login. Major authentication providers like (Microsoft Azure AD) already have integration with BOX.

I was looking into [IndetityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3). 
I can certainly develop SSO for our own .NET and Angular applications, but I was wondering if its possible to integrate it with BOX?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer uses the standard Katana middleware to incorporate external identity providers - if there is one for BOX you can incorporate it.

I did a quick search and could not find anything for BOX. Maybe you have more luck using the above key words - or you need to write a middleware for it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if Box can be an identity provider, it cannot, it is just a service that uses OAuth to generate tokens to allow API access.

Box [SSO](https://community.box.com/t5/For-Admins/Single-Sign-On-SSO-with-Box-For-Administrators/ta-p/1263) allows the other direction, where you to sign in to Box via various identity providers including Azure AD. If Azure AD is not suitable for your needs perhaps one of the other id providers they support is.

Comment: I was not asking if BOX can be identity provider? we will have our own identity server where user will authenticated and issued a access token & ID token. I was wondering we can use that to access BOX service so user doesn't have to login again when browse box web site.

Comment: Here is the answer I received on BOX's developer forum https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/How-to-integrate-BOX-with-IdentityServer3/m-p/18238/highlight/false#M424

Comment: I don't believe IdentityServer implements SAML in the way that would be needed to provide identity to Box, but @leastprivilege would know for sure

Comment: you are correct that identity server doesn't provide SAML. But I was wondering if BOX would support OpenID Connect in near future since SAML is old technology and everyone is moving towards OpenID Connect.